# qtcreator installation issue invalid encoding

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I had previous installation packages for Qt.
/home/star/Downloads/sandeep/Untitled Folder/qt-creator-opensource-linux-x86_64-4.2.1(1).run
/home/star/Downloads/sandeep/Untitled Folder/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.8.0.run
/home/star/Downloads/sandeep/Untitled Folder/qt-unified-linux-x64-2.0.5-1-online.run

I clicked properties and checked "allow package to run"
But when I double click on the run file,�*B@ (invalid encoding) file gets created and it does not execute.

Also, I guess my linux is 32-bit, because output of uname -a gives
Linux star-X555LAB 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 00:06:14 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

and I gues my installables are 4 bit as the name suggests,that may be the problem.

I searched internet and found that it happens when u migrate from windows to linux. So, I formatted my NTFS pen drive to ext and tried again. the same problem repeats.
What should I do now?

I think the current installation packages for qt support only 1 month service. Or is the open-source longer duration free license for qt still valid. if so What is the path to download installables?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. Your OS is 32bit (i686) and your Qt installation is 64bit (x64). You may:

1. Run the binary from terminal and see the output
2. Install 64bit OS
3. Install 32bit Qt toolset